# Using same toString() to access different subclass variables

Tags: printf, tostring, subclass

I am interested in seeing how a single printf statement or @Override toString() method can be used to give accurate information when there are possible different subclasses that may need to be referenced in it.

Here is the Example program set up:

class Animal - String name - int age
class Bird extends Animal - private int feathers - Animal animalObj  //to reference the animal object vars
class Monkey extends Animal - private int weight - Animal animalObj //to reference the animal object vars
class Tree - int heightInFeet - Animal animalInTree //to reference the instantiated animal object

Class tree has a "boolean inTree()" method which if true means the animal is in the tree
class tree has 2 more methods...
public Animal nowInTree()
public Animal hasLeftTree()

each of these methods need a println or printf statement to list out the charastics of the animal as well... Here's the catch, the Bird class has a param int feathers and the Monkey class has a param double weight.

my output to console called form the Tree class should equal somthing like...."The bird named Falcon that is 3 years old with 912 feathers has left the tree."

THEN using the SAME method or perhaps even the same printf statement can ALSO print to console..."The monkey named Bubba who is 9 years old 22.5lbs is its weight has left the tree."

possible printf statement (assumes created super and subclass methods - though this is incomplete =

System.out.printf("The animal named %s who is %d years old $s has left the tree",  animalInTree.getAnimalName(), animalObj.getAge(), wtfGoesHere.callMeth(), );

ok notice that I need to get the var from each of the subclasses which the wtfGoesHere() method represents.  The wtfGoesHere() has to return not only the var weight or feathers but also extra info attached...so not just the weight but "its weight is %d".

Weight and Feathers var have to be private.  Although if publis will that solve it?  If yes, is that still risky coding?  I am an amature still but sometimes working around the privates is chapping my arse.

I am stumped as the compiler currently DOES know the info in the Animal class but not the subclasses of Monkey and Bird.  I can make a getBlaBla() for the info in the sub classes but cannot figure out how to tell java which one to use when.

Possible thoughts...

1. make exception handling and add in an extra param in the printf method and when it hits that field it will use the one it can and throw an exception on the other...If even possible I do not know expcetions yet, I am in advanced java class and that is a month away.  The homework "implies" it will not allow for exception handling.  (although I am curious if this will work)
2. Create some sort of cascading "if else" which will determine which subclass is needed and then.  Still problematic as the methods I am restricted in making do not include passing the subclass objects...only accepting the Animal class as an object param to pass inside the Tree class.
3. Use the Tree class toString() overide method to handle this...although I still bump up against #2 the above.
4. We learned about absract classes and the "implements" functions - So I am open to that as well if this can solve my problem...so long as the hasLeftTree() method can handle both subclass possibilities.  If I didn't specifically state the hasLeftTree() method does specifically call a print statement giving all the info on teh subclass including its animal extension info.

I mention the above to try to show that I have put some thought in this and am not just whining for hand holding.  also, despite the restrictions above my teacher has...on occasion...declared that he wants us to find functions not specifically mentioned in class...so...if you belive that the appropriate industry accepted standard requires going off instructions I will argue that to my professor.

I will provide more code if needed.  Everyting else works in the programs which consists of 4 files...the 3 classes and the main method file.

Thoughts? and TYVM in advance code gods.

Comment: You need to format your code and question properly so that we can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by the understanding that via polymorphism when returning a toString method of a superclass java will look out yonder to the subclasses to see if there is a "better verion" of the toString method...since my object was a subclass object when I call the superclass toString it sees the subclass object and then looks to the subclass to see if there is an identical method...in this case "toString" and when it finds it, it uses that medhod instead.  By doing this all the appropriate info was returned to the print statements etc.